# FusionTablesLayer with Multiple Location columns

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-fusion-tables

So I have a **[FusionTablesLayer](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1RhNg-OI30Vup4hvwU9HiwiRQugIqakTs6EB9dfU)** with multiple location columns all set to a KML value. You can check the coordinates by selecting **"preview KML"** after double clicking on the row. I composed an image to show the various columns of the intended result (to scale).

[image: Multiple Location Columns]

The first column `Islands` is depicted in red, `West` in green, and `East` in blue.
Trying to work with this in a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs9Y8/)** is not working at all. Each layer, when switched to, uses the *same* column. The expected outcome is to show the single green marker to the West when clicking on West, and the single blue marker to the East when clicking on East. Note that these are 3 distinct location columns I'm using on 3 disjoint FusionTableLayers displaying separately.

According to the **[Google Maps API #FusionTablesQuery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesQuery)**, I should be able to select whichever column I want to use as the `Location`. Is it a bug, or am I misreading the docs?

Comment: I think you need to rethink your design. You can have up to 5 fusion table layers on a map, of which one can have up to 5 styles applied to it. [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables)

Comment: Yeah, I know about the 5 styles, that's why I have one layer visible at a time (I've even answered that common question on SO bunch of times too). The point was to select the location value from another column other than the first Location column.

Comment: You can only use one location column at a time in a single layer (or two if one is latitude and the other is longitude).

Comment: Right, the JSFiddle shows that. 3 disjoint layers, each selecting a single column. I'm not asking to show all 3 at the same time, perhaps I was not clear with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra set of quotes around your strings in your queries (make "'Islands'" -> "Islands").

```
    layers = [new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: "Islands", //Location KML with a Polygon and a single Point inside it
            from: table
        },
        styles: styles[0],
        map: map
    }), new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: "West",  //Location KML that is a single Point to the West of Islands Polygon
            from: table
        },
        styles: styles[1]
    }), new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: "East",  //Location KML that is a single Point to the East of Islands Polygon
            from: table
        },
        styles: styles[2]
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vs9Y8/5/)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I overlooked something so simple and thought that I'd already tried it. I had to insert them earlier because of the column name having multiple words.